# onClick event will not fire in firefox or chrome, only in IE

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

in my application, I pull in http code from the server side. When this code is placed into the application - the event will happen when clicked in IE, but not in any other browser. Heres the part of the code that deals with the image that is clicked and the event.

```
<img canExpand="true" style="cursor:hand" id="img34635" src="../images/plus.gif" EntityID="346" EntityCat="35" onclick="LoadChild(this.EntityID, this.EntityCat, 0, this.lnEquip)">
```

LoadChild is a javascript function on the client side of the page. When the image is clicked in anything other than IE , nothing happens. Can anyone see why this is happening? It may be a formatting issue. Thanks again.

edit - here is the javascript function load child

```
 function LoadChild(lnEntityID, lnEntityCat, FullExpand, EquipID) {

            document.getElementById('dropTypes').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('dropTypes').style.background = "white";

            DescStatus = 0;

            if (lnEntityCat == 0) {
               window.status = "Loading the tree...";
               PageMethods.LoadChild(lnEntityID, lnEntityCat, GLOBALEQUIPID, FullExpand, 0, 0, 1, LoadChildCallback);

            }
            else if (document.getElementById('img' + lnEntityID + lnEntityCat).canExpand == "true") {
                if (document.getElementById('div' + lnEntityID + lnEntityCat).style.display == 'none') {
                    document.getElementById('div' + lnEntityID + lnEntityCat).style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('img' + lnEntityID + lnEntityCat).src = "../images/minus.gif"
                    window.status = "Loading the tree...HERE";




                    PageMethods.LoadChild(lnEntityID, lnEntityCat, GLOBALEQUIPID, FullExpand, 0, 0, 1, LoadChildCallback);


                                        }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('div' + lnEntityID + lnEntityCat).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('img' + lnEntityID + lnEntityCat).src = "../images/plus.gif"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you seeing any errors in the console of the other browsers?

Comment: with this html <img> we cannot say where the issue is?Can you post the OnClick for JS?

Comment: the javascript function has been added to the original post.

Comment: Making up your own attributes as you go along? Are you using any other IE-only methods in this? Never, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work. Always make your code work in a modern browser first!

Comment: this was legacy code inherited when i started working at my current job, my job is to finally convert it to modern browsers lol

Answer (score 2):

It's odd but I've known the absence of the semi colon disturb the click event. So try

```
onclick="LoadChild(this.EntityID, this.EntityCat, 0, this.lnEquip);"
```

note the added ;

**OR**

of course you could always use something like jQuery

```
$('#img34635').click(function(){

    LoadChild(this.EntityID, this.EntityCat, 0, this.lnEquip);

});
```

The `bind` or `on` (later versions of JQuery) parts of the API would work equally as well

**OR**

One or more of your parms might need to be surrounded with apostrophes. For instance the param `lnEntityCat` is definitely treated like a string at certain parts of the code.

Honestly - if it's legacy code which it is then there could be all kinds of unpleasantness in the function that disturbs various browsers. I would comment it all out but one or two lines then work up from there. Good luck

Comment: the semi colon did not make a difference, trying to avoid jquery for now, but can look into this if only option.

Comment: Then I might imagine that one or more of the params require apostrophes around them so they are handled correctly as strings. Could that be it?

Comment: It could be, I have posted the javascript function in the first post now. This was very old (had references relating to IE4, and document.all) code that I inherited at a new job.

Comment: all the older references have been removed - no document.all or anything else relating to this remain in the code.

Comment: will be using this with jquery - will report back when finished with answer